# PHP Laravel (Shopify App) how to access Guzzle response(stdclass) data parameters

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, stdclass

I am working on Shopify App using Laravel and used **Osiset/Larave-Shopify** Package.

Currently I am trying to access response from **Shopify Webhooks** and package returns data in **stdclass object.**

Simply I want to access email from the following response object in PHP, can anyone please let me know how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

**Here is response code:**

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => 2222178795622,
   'email' => 'jmmkaler@gmail.com',
   'closed_at' => NULL,
   'created_at' => '2020-05-09T16:39:11-04:00',
   'updated_at' => '2020-05-09T16:39:12-04:00',
   'number' => 3,
   'note' => NULL,
   'token' => '7d485aee4f64562e98444fa11a0acb9d',
   'gateway' => 'bogus',
   'test' => true,
   'total_price' => '590.00',
   'subtotal_price' => '500.00',
   'total_weight' => 0,
   'total_tax' => '90.00',
   'taxes_included' => false,
   'currency' => 'INR',
   'financial_status' => 'paid',
   'confirmed' => true,
   'total_discounts' => '0.00',
   'total_line_items_price' => '500.00',
   'cart_token' => '',
   'buyer_accepts_marketing' => false,
   'name' => '#1003',
   'referring_site' => 'https://shipment-tracker.myshopify.com/products/jeans-1',
   'landing_site' => '/wallets/checkouts.json',
   'cancelled_at' => NULL,
   'cancel_reason' => NULL,
   'total_price_usd' => '7.82',
   'checkout_token' => '587a1c76ed68ae90c521de803bb6c9b7',
   'reference' => NULL,
   'user_id' => NULL,
   'location_id' => NULL,
   'source_identifier' => NULL,
   'source_url' => NULL,
   'processed_at' => '2020-05-09T16:39:11-04:00',
   'device_id' => NULL,
   'phone' => NULL,
   'customer_locale' => 'en',
   'app_id' => 580111,
   'browser_ip' => '117.203.132.178',
   'landing_site_ref' => NULL,
   'order_number' => 1003,
   'discount_applications' => 
  array (
  ),
   'discount_codes' => 
  array (
  ),
   'note_attributes' => 
  array (
  ),
   'payment_gateway_names' => 
  array (
    0 => 'bogus',
  ),
   'processing_method' => 'direct',
   'checkout_id' => 12780937707622,
   'source_name' => 'web',
   'fulfillment_status' => NULL,
   'tax_lines' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'price' => '90.00',
       'rate' => 0.179999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125,
       'title' => 'IGST',
       'price_set' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'shop_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '90.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
         'presentment_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '90.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
      )),
    )),
  ),
   'tags' => '',
   'contact_email' => 'jmmkaler@gmail.com',
   'order_status_url' => 'https://shipment-tracker.myshopify.com/27247083622/orders/7d485aee4f64562e98444fa11a0acb9d/authenticate?key=4177ec29bf6e0a924cbc981827e0c5c8',
   'presentment_currency' => 'INR',
   'total_line_items_price_set' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'shop_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '500.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
     'presentment_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '500.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
  )),
   'total_discounts_set' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'shop_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '0.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
     'presentment_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '0.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
  )),
   'total_shipping_price_set' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'shop_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '0.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
     'presentment_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '0.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
  )),
   'subtotal_price_set' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'shop_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '500.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
     'presentment_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '500.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
  )),
   'total_price_set' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'shop_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '590.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
     'presentment_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '590.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
  )),
   'total_tax_set' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'shop_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '90.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
     'presentment_money' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'amount' => '90.00',
       'currency_code' => 'INR',
    )),
  )),
   'line_items' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 4852532740198,
       'variant_id' => 31739432435814,
       'title' => 'Jeans',
       'quantity' => 1,
       'sku' => '',
       'variant_title' => '',
       'vendor' => 'Nike',
       'fulfillment_service' => 'manual',
       'product_id' => 4818366496870,
       'requires_shipping' => true,
       'taxable' => true,
       'gift_card' => false,
       'name' => 'Jeans',
       'variant_inventory_management' => 'shopify',
       'properties' => 
      array (
      ),
       'product_exists' => true,
       'fulfillable_quantity' => 1,
       'grams' => 0,
       'price' => '500.00',
       'total_discount' => '0.00',
       'fulfillment_status' => NULL,
       'price_set' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'shop_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '500.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
         'presentment_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '500.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
      )),
       'total_discount_set' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'shop_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '0.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
         'presentment_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '0.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
      )),
       'discount_allocations' => 
      array (
      ),
       'duties' => 
      array (
      ),
       'admin_graphql_api_id' => 'gid://shopify/LineItem/4852532740198',
       'tax_lines' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'title' => 'IGST',
           'price' => '90.00',
           'rate' => 0.179999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125,
           'price_set' => 
          stdClass::__set_state(array(
             'shop_money' => 
            stdClass::__set_state(array(
               'amount' => '90.00',
               'currency_code' => 'INR',
            )),
             'presentment_money' => 
            stdClass::__set_state(array(
               'amount' => '90.00',
               'currency_code' => 'INR',
            )),
          )),
        )),
      ),
       'origin_location' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'id' => 1939741409382,
         'country_code' => 'IN',
         'province_code' => 'PB',
         'name' => 'Shipment-tracker',
         'address1' => 'Jalandhar',
         'address2' => '',
         'city' => 'Jalandhar',
         'zip' => '144401',
      )),
    )),
  ),
   'fulfillments' => 
  array (
  ),
   'refunds' => 
  array (
  ),
   'total_tip_received' => '0.0',
   'original_total_duties_set' => NULL,
   'current_total_duties_set' => NULL,
   'admin_graphql_api_id' => 'gid://shopify/Order/2222178795622',
   'shipping_lines' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 1839082045542,
       'title' => 'Standard',
       'price' => '0.00',
       'code' => 'Standard',
       'source' => 'shopify',
       'phone' => NULL,
       'requested_fulfillment_service_id' => NULL,
       'delivery_category' => NULL,
       'carrier_identifier' => NULL,
       'discounted_price' => '0.00',
       'price_set' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'shop_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '0.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
         'presentment_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '0.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
      )),
       'discounted_price_set' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'shop_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '0.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
         'presentment_money' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'amount' => '0.00',
           'currency_code' => 'INR',
        )),
      )),
       'discount_allocations' => 
      array (
      ),
       'tax_lines' => 
      array (
      ),
    )),
  ),
   'billing_address' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'first_name' => 'Jimmy',
     'address1' => 'near ravidas mandir,nawashehar road Village Garha',
     'phone' => NULL,
     'city' => 'PHILLAUR',
     'zip' => '144410',
     'province' => 'Punjab',
     'country' => 'India',
     'last_name' => 'Kaler',
     'address2' => 'wuhawosu',
     'company' => NULL,
     'latitude' => NULL,
     'longitude' => NULL,
     'name' => 'Jimmy Kaler',
     'country_code' => 'IN',
     'province_code' => 'PB',
  )),
   'shipping_address' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'first_name' => 'Jimmy',
     'address1' => 'near ravidas mandir,nawashehar road Village Garha',
     'phone' => NULL,
     'city' => 'PHILLAUR',
     'zip' => '144410',
     'province' => 'Punjab',
     'country' => 'India',
     'last_name' => 'Kaler',
     'address2' => 'wuhawosu',
     'company' => NULL,
     'latitude' => NULL,
     'longitude' => NULL,
     'name' => 'Jimmy Kaler',
     'country_code' => 'IN',
     'province_code' => 'PB',
  )),
   'client_details' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'browser_ip' => '117.203.132.178',
     'accept_language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8',
     'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
     'session_hash' => NULL,
     'browser_width' => 1349,
     'browser_height' => 657,
  )),
   'payment_details' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'credit_card_bin' => '1',
     'avs_result_code' => NULL,
     'cvv_result_code' => NULL,
     'credit_card_number' => '•••• •••• •••• 1',
     'credit_card_company' => 'Bogus',
  )),
   'customer' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => 3003356774502,
     'email' => 'jmmkaler@gmail.com',
     'accepts_marketing' => true,
     'created_at' => '2020-04-24T17:09:53-04:00',
     'updated_at' => '2020-05-09T16:39:11-04:00',
     'first_name' => 'Jimmy',
     'last_name' => 'Kaler',
     'orders_count' => 0,
     'state' => 'disabled',
     'total_spent' => '0.00',
     'last_order_id' => NULL,
     'note' => NULL,
     'verified_email' => true,
     'multipass_identifier' => NULL,
     'tax_exempt' => false,
     'phone' => NULL,
     'tags' => 'password page, prospect',
     'last_order_name' => NULL,
     'currency' => 'INR',
     'accepts_marketing_updated_at' => '2020-04-24T17:09:53-04:00',
     'marketing_opt_in_level' => 'single_opt_in',
     'admin_graphql_api_id' => 'gid://shopify/Customer/3003356774502',
     'default_address' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 3312853745766,
       'customer_id' => 3003356774502,
       'first_name' => 'Jimmy',
       'last_name' => 'Kaler',
       'company' => NULL,
       'address1' => 'near ravidas mandir,nawashehar road Village Garha',
       'address2' => 'wuhawosu',
       'city' => 'PHILLAUR',
       'province' => 'Punjab',
       'country' => 'India',
       'zip' => '144410',
       'phone' => NULL,
       'name' => 'Jimmy Kaler',
       'province_code' => 'PB',
       'country_code' => 'IN',
       'country_name' => 'India',
       'default' => true,
    )),
  )),
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above is a var_dump or print_r of the actual object then do:

```
$object->email;
```

//another example of different object User

```
class User
{
    public $name = 'John';
    public $age = 34;
    private $salary = 4200.00;
    protected $identifier = 'ABC';
}

$user = new User();
var_export($user); // outputs string "User::__set_state..."

echo $user->name;
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris